# How to get the item index of tabview generated list on each tab?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
body: TabBarView(
          children:
            List<Widget>.generate(_poiCatList.length, (int index){
              _poiList = poi.currentPoiList.where((poi) => poi.IsActive == true && poi.IsFeatured == false && poi.CG_CATPOI_ID == _poiCatList[index].Id).toList(); // filtra pois pela cat
              return new ListView(
                  children:
                    List<Widget>.generate(_poiList.length, (int index){
                      return new ListTile(
                          title: new Text(_poiList[index].Title, style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
                          subtitle: new Text(_poiList[index].Address),
                          leading: new Icon(
                            Icons.place,
                            color: Colors.blue[500],
                          ),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentSelectPoi = _poiList[index].Id;
                            });
                            _poi = poi.currentPoiList.indexWhere((poi) => poi.Id == _currentSelectPoi);
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => CityPoiDetail(poi.currentPoiList[_poi]),
                            ));
                          },
                      );
                    }
                   )
              );
            }),
      ),
```

I'm only able to get the index of the last generated item.
I generate dinamicly the tabs, then i generate dinamicly the content for each tab, but on the tap event for each generated listtile i can only get the index of the last one.

Comment: I'm using this approach and it works the only problem is after the creation of the tabarview based on the categories, using listview's and listtile, the ontap cannot identify each taped item from each individual category tab, only the last one created.

Comment: Why don't you change the index for the tab to `tabIndex` and that of the list tile to `tileIndex` instead of having both named `index`?

Comment: @sudo_kaizen i did changed the index, but the problem remains.. i can identify the tabindex on the tabbarview, but what i cant do is identify the item from each of the tabbarview widgets.. i got for instances 2 tabs, each with a listview with 2 items, on the ontap of each item (listtile), i cant seem to identify each item only the last one..

Comment: This is quite hard to understand. Can you provide a visual representation of what you are trying to explain? Can you provide a dartpad? It would be more helpful

Comment: Let me re-explain to you what I understand. You are trying to say that you have tabs on your app which are generated dynamically. Now, the view or content of each tab contains list items that are generated dynamically too. When you click on a list item, the event that occurs does so for the list item above the one you clicked. Is that it?

Comment: @sudo_kaizen it was my own fault, the problem was here: _poiList = poi.currentPoiList.where((poi) => poi.IsActive == true && poi.IsFeatured == false && poi.CG_CATPOI_ID == _poiCatList[tabIndex].Id).toList(); ... just fixed it, and the behaviour now is what it would be expected..